# how to do zip in scala df and add a column as key

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a df something as below

```
sku  store  inhand  storeQuantity
1    2222   3        34
1    3333   5        45
2    4444   5        56
2    5555   6        67
2    6666   7        67
```

I able to group the data based in sku and then collect_list based on store , inhand ,stoteQuantity .
then I zipped all three.

```
 val groupedDf=  df.groupBy("sku").
      agg(
      collect_list(("store") ) as "store",
      collect_list(("inhand") ) as "inhand",
      collect_list(("storeQuantity") ) as "storeQuantity"

    ).withColumn("Str", zipper(col("store"), col("inhand"),col("storeQuantity"))).drop("store").drop("inhand").drop("storeQuantity")




val zipper = udf((xs: Seq[String], ys: Seq[String], zs: Seq[String]) =>

      (xs, ys, zs).zipped.toSeq)
```

I am able the zip the information as below

```
sku  str
1   [[222, 3, 34],[3333,5,45]]
```

but I want  store as the key as below, how can I achieve this?

```
sku  str
1   [[2222,[ 3, 34],[3333,[5,45]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for using a UDF. Just apply `struct` like below and aggregate with `groupBy`.

```
val dfNew = df
  .withColumn("storeStruct", struct($"store", struct($"inhand", $"storeQuantity").as("storeInfo")))
  .groupBy("sku").agg(collect_list("storeStruct").as("info"))

dfNew.show(false)
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|sku|info                                               |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{2222, {3, 34}}, {3333, {5, 45}}]                 |
|2  |[{4444, {5, 56}}, {5555, {6, 67}}, {6666, {7, 67}}]|
+---+---------------------------------------------------+

dfNew.toJSON.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"sku":1,"info":[{"store":2222,"storeInfo":{"inhand":3,"storeQuantity":34}},{"store":3333,"storeInfo":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":45}}]}                                                           |
|{"sku":2,"info":[{"store":4444,"storeInfo":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":56}},{"store":5555,"storeInfo":{"inhand":6,"storeQuantity":67}},{"store":6666,"storeInfo":{"inhand":7,"storeQuantity":67}}]}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Test Mirror.  The result I am expecting is - { "SKU": "1", "info": [ { "2222": { "inhand": "3", "storeQuantity": "34" }, { "3333": { "inhand": "5", "storeQuantity": "45" } } ] }  . How can we have store as the key for  every struct

Comment: You can apply `toJSON` to generate the JSON strings. I have expanded the answer.

Comment: fieldname instead  of col2  I want it to the value of store
Example - |{"sku":2,"info":[{"store":4444,"4444":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":56}},{"store":5555,"5555":{"inhand":6,"storeQuantity":67}}

Comment: I have further modified the answer with some newly added column names. Please rename them as you see fit.

Comment: The field storeinfo , i want it the actual value of store , example -
{"sku":1,"info":[{"store":2222,"2222":{"inhand":3,"storeQuantity":34}},{"store":3333,"3333":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":45}}]}

Comment: Having variable keys would make the strings non-standard JSON. There might be a way to manually assemble such strings but I wouldn't recommend going down that path.